# Overflow in constants (specifically in .byte) assembler directives (especially gas and clang)

Tags: assembly, clang, gnu-assembler

Is there a way to have the assembler (gas or clang) output an error, not a warning, if the operand to a `.byte` directive overflows?

I'm specifically thinking of constructs such as this on ARM:

```
    tbb [pc, r1]
.L6:
    .byte   (.L12-.L6)/2
    .byte   (.L11-.L6)/2
    .byte   (.L10-.L6)/2
    .byte   (.L9-.L6)/2
    .byte   (.L8-.L6)/2
    .byte   (.L7-.L6)/2
    .byte   (.L5-.L6)/2
```

It works only if the `(.L12-.L6)/2` etc. expressions fit in [-128, 255]. Is there any way to check this at assembly time?

(Maybe I could use conditional directives but this seems quite awkward!)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, constant expressions that overflow a byte directive produce a warning, but expressions derived from labels produce an error. Which is what I want.